# .Net Core 3.1 MVC Authentication Individual User Accounts and Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, scaffolding, asp.net-core-identity

Following this guide:

Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

If I run the app, and click on the "Register" link from the navbar, it redirects to: https://localhost:44397/Identity/Account/Register
but if I try to create a new account and register

> I get This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the
> site owner. HTTP ERROR 400  The same applies to the Login page

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail and explain where you are in the document where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Usually,the simplest steps to create a scaffolding project are as follows.

**1:Create a new project then change the Authentication:**
[image]

**2:Click the project Add and then click New Scaffolded Item.**
[image]

**3:Chooes Identity then add:**
[image]

**4:Override all files and choose the context as ApplicationDbContext then add**
[image]

**5:Migration and run project.Register first and then log in**

Comment: Hi @Ismail,if my answer is helpful,can you [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?Thank you very much!

Comment: HI @Yinqiu after  in Point 5 i added add migration it was added migration file but in update-database changes will not reflected in DB

Can you please help